Некорректно работает сохранение игры в яндекс играх
Я написал игру на юнити и решил выложить в яндекс игры. Но возникла проблема с сохранениями. При выполнении игры, все сохраняется корректно. Но стоит выйти из игры и зайти обратно - часть сохранений сбрасывается. А именно, data.CardsList и data.AchievementsList (но думаю, проблема идентичная, так что говорю только про data.CardsList). Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут заключается проблема?
Файл mainMenu (с него начинается игра)
 [SerializeField] public double total_breads;
 [SerializeField] double breads;
 public TMP_Text breadsOutput, profiPerHourOutput;
 double profitPerHour;
 public int clicksAmount;
 NumbersReduction NumRec;
 CardsManager CardsManager;
 public CardInfo[] RegularCardsList, SpecialCardsList, LegendCardsList;
 public CardInfo[][] cardsListsArray;
 public TimeBonus tb;
 public GameObject effect;
 public GameObject button;
 public AudioSource audioSource;
 DataStructure clientData;

 private void Start() {
     clientData = SavesJSON.LoadData();
     clientData.AplicationWasClosed = false;
     audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
     breads = clientData.Breads;
     total_breads = clientData.TotalBreads;
     clicksAmount = clientData.ClicksAmount;
     profitPerHour = clientData.ProfitPerHour;
     NumRec = new NumbersReduction();
     StartCoroutine(AutoFarm());
 }
 void Update()
 {
     if (GameObject.Find("Balance_Value")) breadsOutput.text = NumRec.NumberReduction((int)breads);
     if (GameObject.Find("ProfitPerHour_Value")) profiPerHourOutput.text = NumRec.NumberReduction(profitPerHour);
 }

 void OnDisable()
 {
     
     SaveGameData();
 }

 void OnApplicationQuit()
 {
     clientData.AplicationWasClosed = true;
     SavesJSON.CreateData(clientData);
 }

 void SaveGameData()
 {
     clientData.Breads = (int)breads;
     clientData.TotalBreads = (int)total_breads;
     clientData.ClicksAmount = clicksAmount;
     clientData.ProfitPerHour = profitPerHour;
     SavesJSON.CreateData(clientData);
 }

Файл savesJSON, который отвечает за реализацию сохранений:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using YG;

public class DataStructure : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Breads { get; set; }
    public int TotalBreads { get; set; }
    public double ProfitPerHour { get; set; }
    public int ClicksAmount { get; set; }
    public bool FirstPurchase { get; set; }
    public bool UnknowCardBought { get; set; }
    public bool AplicationWasClosed { get; set; }
    public string LastSession { get; set; }
    public double TimeInGame { get; set; }
    public List<CardInfo> CardsList { get; set; } = new List<CardInfo>();
    public List<AchievementsInfo> AchievementsList { get; set; } = new List<AchievementsInfo>();
}

public class SavesJSON : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void CreateData(DataStructure clientData)
    {
        DataStructure data = new DataStructure();

        // Проверяем, существует ли файл и загружаем данные, если он существует
        //if (File.Exists("Assets/Scripts/Saves/datajson.json"))
        //{
        //    string json = File.ReadAllText("Assets/Scripts/Saves/datajson.json");
        //    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataStructure>(json);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    // Если файла нет, создаём новый объект
        //    data = new DataStructure();
        //}

        // Обновляем данные
        data.Breads = clientData.Breads;
        data.TotalBreads = clientData.TotalBreads;
        if (clientData.ProfitPerHour > 0) data.ProfitPerHour = clientData.ProfitPerHour;
        if (clientData.ClicksAmount > 0) data.ClicksAmount = clientData.ClicksAmount;
        if (clientData.FirstPurchase) data.FirstPurchase = clientData.FirstPurchase;
        if (clientData.LastSession != null) data.LastSession = clientData.LastSession;
        if (clientData.TimeInGame > 0) data.TimeInGame = clientData.TimeInGame;
        data.AplicationWasClosed = clientData.AplicationWasClosed;


        if (clientData.AchievementsList.Count > 0)
        {
            AchievementsInfo[] AchievementsArray = clientData.AchievementsList.ToArray();
            data.AchievementsList.Clear();
            data.AchievementsList.AddRange(AchievementsArray);
        }
        if (clientData.CardsList.Count > 0)
        {
            CardInfo[] CardsArray = clientData.CardsList.ToArray();
            data.CardsList.Clear();
            data.CardsList.AddRange(CardsArray);
        }

        YandexGame.savesData.Breads = data.Breads;
        YandexGame.savesData.TotalBreads = data.TotalBreads;
        YandexGame.savesData.ProfitPerHour = data.ProfitPerHour;
        YandexGame.savesData.ClicksAmount = data.ClicksAmount;
        YandexGame.savesData.FirstPurchase = data.FirstPurchase;
        YandexGame.savesData.UnknowCardBought = data.UnknowCardBought;
        YandexGame.savesData.AplicationWasClosed = data.AplicationWasClosed;
        YandexGame.savesData.LastSession = data.LastSession;
        YandexGame.savesData.TimeInGame = data.TimeInGame;
        YandexGame.savesData.CardsList = data.CardsList;
        YandexGame.savesData.AchievementsList = data.AchievementsList;
        Debug.Log("ПРОЦЕСС СОХРАНЕНИЯ");
        foreach (var card in YandexGame.savesData.CardsList)
        {
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].name = " + card.name);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].alreadyBought = " + card.alreadyBought);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].available = " + card.available);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].level = " + card.level);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].base_price = " + card.base_price);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].base_profit = " + card.base_profit);
        }
        YandexGame.SaveProgress();
        // Сериализуем и записываем обратно в файл
        //string datajson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        //File.WriteAllText("Assets/Scripts/Saves/datajson.json", datajson);
    }

    public static DataStructure LoadData()
    {
        //string json = File.ReadAllText("Assets/Scripts/Saves/datajson.json");
        //DataStructure data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataStructure>(json);
        DataStructure data = new DataStructure();
        data.Breads = YandexGame.savesData.Breads;
        data.TotalBreads = YandexGame.savesData.TotalBreads;
        data.ProfitPerHour = YandexGame.savesData.ProfitPerHour;
        data.ClicksAmount = YandexGame.savesData.ClicksAmount;
        data.FirstPurchase = YandexGame.savesData.FirstPurchase;
        data.UnknowCardBought = YandexGame.savesData.UnknowCardBought;
        data.AplicationWasClosed = YandexGame.savesData.AplicationWasClosed;
        data.LastSession = YandexGame.savesData.LastSession;
        data.TimeInGame = YandexGame.savesData.TimeInGame;
        CardInfo[] CardsArray = YandexGame.savesData.CardsList.ToArray();
        data.CardsList.Clear();
        data.CardsList.AddRange(CardsArray);
        AchievementsInfo[] AchievementsArray = YandexGame.savesData.AchievementsList.ToArray();
        data.AchievementsList.Clear();
        data.AchievementsList.AddRange(AchievementsArray);

        Debug.Log("ЗАГРУЗКА СОХРАНЕНИЯ");
        Debug.Log(" data.Breads = " + data.Breads);
        Debug.Log(" data.TotalBreads = " + data.TotalBreads);
        Debug.Log(" data.ProfitPerHour = " + data.ProfitPerHour);
        Debug.Log(" data.ClicksAmount = " + data.ClicksAmount);
        Debug.Log(" data.FirstPurchase = " + data.FirstPurchase);
        Debug.Log(" data.UnknowCardBought = " + data.UnknowCardBought);
        Debug.Log(" data.AplicationWasClosed = " + data.AplicationWasClosed);
        Debug.Log(" data.LastSession = " + data.LastSession);
        Debug.Log(" data.TimeInGame = " + data.TimeInGame);
        foreach (var card in data.CardsList)
        {
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].name = " + card.name);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].alreadyBought = " + card.alreadyBought);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].available = " + card.available);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].level = " + card.level);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].base_price = " + card.base_price);
            Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].base_profit = " + card.base_profit);
        }

        return data;
    }
}

Файл с карточками (где и возникает проблема)

    DataStructure clientData;
    public double breads, total_breads;
    public double profitPerHour;
    string PathCardLevel_Value, PathCardProfit_Value, PathCardPrice_Value, PathCardFutureProfit_Value;
    Transform CardLevel_Value, CardProfit_Value, CardPrice_Value, CardFutureProfit_Value;
    TMP_Text TCardLevel_Value, TCardProfit_Value, TCardPrice_Value, TCardFutureProfit_Value;
    NumbersReduction NumRed;
    public CardInfo[] RegularCardsList, SpecialCardsList, LegendCardsList;
    public TMP_Text breadsOutput;

    void Start()
    {
        GetLoad();

        NumRed = new NumbersReduction();
        StartCoroutine(AutoFarm());
    }


    void OnDisable()
    {
        SaveGameData();
    }


    public void GetLoad()
    {

        clientData = SavesJSON.LoadData();
        breads = (double)clientData.Breads;
        total_breads = (double)clientData.TotalBreads;
        profitPerHour = clientData.ProfitPerHour;
        LoadCardsData();
    }

    public void SaveGameData()
    {
        //var regularCardsList = new List<CardInfo>(RegularCardsList);
        //var specialCardsList = new List<CardInfo>(SpecialCardsList);
        //var legendCardsList = new List<CardInfo>(LegendCardsList);

        clientData.CardsList.Clear();
        clientData.CardsList.AddRange(RegularCardsList);
        clientData.CardsList.AddRange(SpecialCardsList);
        clientData.CardsList.AddRange(LegendCardsList);
        Debug.Log("clientData.CardsList.Count = " + clientData.CardsList.Count);
        foreach (var card in clientData.CardsList)
        {
            Debug.Log("card.name = " + card.name);
        }

        clientData.Breads = (int)breads;
        clientData.TotalBreads = (int)total_breads;

        // Создаем JSON данные
        SavesJSON.CreateData(clientData);
    }


    void LoadCardsData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clientData.CardsList.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("МАГАЗИН");
            Debug.Log("clientData.CardsList.Count = " + clientData.CardsList.Count);
            if (RegularCardsList.Length >= i && clientData.CardsList[i].category == "Regular")
            {
                RegularCardsList[i].alreadyBought = clientData.CardsList[i].alreadyBought;
                RegularCardsList[i].available = clientData.CardsList[i].available;
                RegularCardsList[i].level = clientData.CardsList[i].level;
                RegularCardsList[i].base_price = clientData.CardsList[i].base_price;
                RegularCardsList[i].base_profit = clientData.CardsList[i].base_profit;
                Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].name = " + RegularCardsList[i].name);
                Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].alreadyBought = " + RegularCardsList[i].alreadyBought);
                Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].available = " + RegularCardsList[i].available);
                Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].level = " + RegularCardsList[i].level);
                Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].base_price = " + RegularCardsList[i].base_price);
                Debug.Log("RegularCardsList[i].base_profit = " + RegularCardsList[i].base_profit);

            }
            if (SpecialCardsList.Length >= i && clientData.CardsList[i].category == "Special")
            {
                SpecialCardsList[i].alreadyBought = clientData.CardsList[i].alreadyBought;
                SpecialCardsList[i].available = clientData.CardsList[i].available;
                SpecialCardsList[i].level = clientData.CardsList[i].level;
                SpecialCardsList[i].base_price = clientData.CardsList[i].base_price;
                SpecialCardsList[i].base_profit = clientData.CardsList[i].base_profit;
            }
            if (LegendCardsList.Length >= i && clientData.CardsList[i].category == "Legend")
            {
                LegendCardsList[i].alreadyBought = clientData.CardsList[i].alreadyBought;
                LegendCardsList[i].available = clientData.CardsList[i].available;
                LegendCardsList[i].level = clientData.CardsList[i].level;
                LegendCardsList[i].base_price = clientData.CardsList[i].base_price;
                LegendCardsList[i].base_profit = clientData.CardsList[i].base_profit;
            }
        }
    }

SavesYG:

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YG
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class SavesYG
    {
        // "Технические сохранения" для работы плагина (Не удалять)
        public int idSave;
        public bool isFirstSession = true;
        public string language = "ru";
        public bool promptDone;

        // Тестовые сохранения для демо сцены
        // Можно удалить этот код, но тогда удалите и демо (папка Example)


        // Ваши сохранения

        public int Breads;
        public int TotalBreads;
        public double ProfitPerHour;
        public int ClicksAmount;
        public bool FirstPurchase;
        public bool UnknowCardBought;
        public bool AplicationWasClosed;
        public string LastSession;
        public double TimeInGame;
        public List<CardInfo> CardsList;
        public List<AchievementsInfo> AchievementsList;

        // Поля (сохранения) можно удалять и создавать новые. При обновлении игры сохранения ломаться не должны


        // Вы можете выполнить какие то действия при загрузке сохранений
        public SavesYG()
        {
            // Допустим, задать значения по умолчанию для отдельных элементов массива

            //openLevels[1] = true;
        }
    }
}


